# Get an error when consuming a WCF server from .Net Core 2.1 but it's fine on .NET

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I have a WCF service (AIF) on Microsoft Dynamics AX

I can call it without any problem using `.NET 4.6.1`. However, when I run the same exact code using `.NET Core` I get an error which states

> A call to SSPI failed The target principal name is incorrect

[image]

There are many alike questions out there about this error but the solutions does not fix my problem.

```
    var service = new MarketplaceGetItemsDataServiceClient();
    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "UserName";
    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "P@ssword";
    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "Domain";
    var result = service.GetItemsDataAsync(new CallContext(), new SearchOptionsDC() { VendorId = "0000" }).Result;
```

Answer (score 4):

In Connected Services\MyService\Rference.cs file find the method GetEndpointAddress() and add the UpnEndpointIdentity with your identity account.

```
private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.NetTcpBinding_MyService))
        {
            return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(
                new System.Uri(@"net.tcp://190.188.1.2:8201/DynamicsAx/Services/MyService"), 
                new System.ServiceModel.UpnEndpointIdentity("host@host.com")
                );
        }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
    }
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

Change the DNS and replace it with the IP in the WCF tool.

Comment: Can you please read this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and edit your answer?

Comment: Can you explain why this workaround works, and maybe point me at some documentation about this ? We have this issue, but can't really use IP addresses.